# Apache and users write permission issues

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, unix, www-data

On my web server I have two distinct folders, `/home/dev/` and `/home/prod/`, each containing several websites.

As you can guess, each directory is owned by the corresponding user, `dev`and `prod`.

The permissions I put on the directories and its subdirectories are the following :

```
 drwxrwsr-x dev  www-data
 drwxrwsr-x prod www-data
```

The directories are `2775` and the files are `0664`.

Both users `dev` and `prod` are part of the `www-data` group.

With this configuration, both `dev` and `prod` are able to read and write their own files, but Apache appears not to be able to write.

For example, when I want to install a Drupal module through the backoffice, or when I want to update a Wordpress core, I get asked my FTP login.
Which is weird since everything has `www-data`as owner group.
Setting `www-data` as owner fixes the problem but then `dev`and `prod` can't modify their files anymore.

So the question is, how can I keep all files editable by their respective owners while making them writable by Apache ?

Thank you !

Comment: I'm confused - something is not right.  Please post the output of two commands: #1 -- ps -ef | egrep '(apache|httpd)';   #2 -- id apache;  - thanks.  The semicolons are there for clarity, not required.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Here are the outputs : http://pastebin.com/bd0TvczQ